# How to keep long image within background cover at any screen size in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to put a gif of a mobile app within a background 'cover' in CSS. On larger screens, it looks fine - the gif will load correctly as shown below:
[image]

However on even slightly smaller screens I can't get the image to scale down properly, and get overflow like this:
[image]

The CSS for the 'cover' background is as follows:

```
#deck{
    background:url('test3bg.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    top:104px;
    left:0;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;  
    width:100%;
    height:70%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

And for the app demo it's

```
#appDemo{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:600px;
    background:url('appDemo.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:330px;
    right:8%;
    top:30px;
}
```

HTML for the background image area and its children:

```
<div id="deck">
        <div id="leader">
            <div id="main">Lorem ipsum <span id="anything">dolor</span></div>
            <div id="subtitle">lorem ipsum dolor<br><span id="subtitleEmph">lorem ipsum... dolor</span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="dog">
            <img src="dog2.png" style="opacity:0;">
        </div>
        <div id="appDemo">

        </div>

    </div>
```

Other relevant CSS for the background area:

```
#dog{
    background:url('dog1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-size:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    margin-top:-188px;
    left:12%;

}
#leader{
    font-family: 'montserratultra_light', sans-serif;
    font-weight:200;
    font-size:45px;
    color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    left:15%;
    top:26%;
}
#anything{
    font-family: 'montserratlight', sans-serif;
    color:#ef473a;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #ef473a;
    font-style:italic;
}
#leader #subtitle{
    font-family: 'montserratlight', sans-serif;
    font-size:28px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
#subtitle #subtitleEmph{
    font-family: 'montserratregular', sans-serif;
    color:#ef473a;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

I tried all sorts of silly things, such as writing JavaScript functions to rescale the background-size depending on document size and window size, yet this felt unnecessary. Does anyone know of a reasonable CSS solution to this problem?

Comment: That doesn't look like a `background-size` issue, but that the actual size of the element containing the phone image is incorrectly sized. We can't really help you without seeing a demo of the site, or at least your HTML and CSS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I added in more relevant HTML/CSS as per your request! Thank you so much :-)

Comment: The height of #appDemo div should not be absolute if you want it to scale along width your responsive cover..

Comment: @Goombah that's true but with height as auto or undefined, the image doesn't show up at all because of its absolute positioning, maybe a child div with relative positioning containing the image would solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the css of `#appDemo` like this:

```
#appDemo{
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    height:60%; /*you might need to play with this setting*/
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow:hidden; /*<-- added so that it does not disappear with auto width*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:330px;
    right:8%;
    top:30px;
}
```

and add the image as an `<img>` element to the div instead of background image.